# Integrate my app with OK Google

Tags: android, google-search

I would like to integrate Google search with my App. Is it possible? Like for example? If I say OK Google - "Delete record 1 in my App name" - It should do required process in my App.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Integrate voice recognition functionality in your app.

Comment: I don't want that. For example: I can say OK Google in my Nexus 5 give commands. I would like to integrate it into that.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways: essentially set one of the existing "Ok, Google" commands to do what you want, like starting your app rather then Maps, or you can customize your app to respond to "Ok, Google start 'app name'" calls.  More details are in the [Android Wear documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html).  It may be specific to Wear in some aspects, but should carry to handhelds as well, and at least get you pointed in the right direction.